# PHP MySQL - Order Alpha and Numeric strings

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, numeric

I have the following data:

```
GROUP 1 - FINANCE
GROUP 10 - SALES
GROUP 11 - MARKETING
GROUP 12 - HR
GROUP 2 - OPS
```

When `ORDERING` the data in a MySQL question it, rightly, brings this data back in the above order.  However, is there anyway (without changing the data you can order it in `Numeric` order?  As follows

```
GROUP 1 - FINANCE
GROUP 2 - OPS
GROUP 10 - SALES
GROUP 11 - MARKETING
GROUP 12 - HR
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is that column was numerical in the database it would do it automatically. Can you change the schema? Otherwise a simple cast to int before ordering would work. p.s I'm pretty sure this question has been answered many times on here already and a simple google would also sort it.

Comment: Here is an article that might be helpful. https://www.copterlabs.com/natural-sorting-in-mysql/ as @webnoob mentioned, you would be better off changing the schema, but if that's not possible, you would have a much easier time implementing a sort in php IMO (which is perfectly acceptable if the data set is small).

Comment: have you got any column which show it number? because if you want to sort by numbers you need numeric column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ORDER BY 
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED)` clause should help.

Nesting `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions with the right parameters makes it possible to split and extract the string parts. it this case the numeric part after the first string part in this case 'GROUP' will be extracted.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 records.data
FROM (

SELECT 
 "GROUP 1 - FINANCE" AS data
UNION 
SELECT 
 "GROUP 10 - SALES" AS data
UNION 
SELECT 
 "GROUP 11 - MARKETING" AS data 
UNION 
SELECT 
 "GROUP 12 - HR" AS data  
UNION 
SELECT 
 "GROUP 2 - OPS" AS data   
) AS records
ORDER BY 
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(records.data, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sGqUeTKaDjihRA3Bg3Myca/0

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) to `ORDER BY` the column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY CAST(TRIM(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '(GROUP )([0-9]+)'), 'GROUP', '')) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't understand `INT` as a CAST type (you get a parse error) you need to use `UNSIGNED` instead.  see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkzdNKhdeTJbsko4GbkNAg/0